# Getting error when adding locator but this one is working in normal code but when I convent this on testcase that time getting error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation

```
def test_blank_email_validation(driver):
global email
email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='email']")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of(email)
    )
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    email.send_keys('jkhdkasjh')
    email.clear()
    expected_text = "Email cannot be empty"
    # Wait for the element to become visible (maximum wait time: 10 seconds)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(text(), '{expected_text}')]"))
    )
    eval1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(text(), '{expected_text}')]")
    assert eval1.text == expected_text
except NoSuchElementException:
    pytest.fail('Error: Invalid validation message')
```

This code I am getting error:

```
driver = <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="97b05005aa11644e7f5aa08a7b3f069f")>

def test_blank_email_validation(driver):
    try:
        global email
>       email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='email']")

auth/test_login.py:38: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:738: in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:344: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x10d51ff50>
response = {'status': 404, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\...ff80b01e4e1 _pthread_start + 125\\n20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80b019f6b thread_start + 15\\n"}}'}

    def check_response(self, response: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        """Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an
        error.
    
        :Args:
         - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
           object.
    
        :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
        """
        status = response.get("status", None)
        if not status or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
            return
        value = None
        message = response.get("message", "")
        screen: str = response.get("screen", "")
        stacktrace = None
        if isinstance(status, int):
            value_json = response.get("value", None)
            if value_json and isinstance(value_json, str):
                import json
    
                try:
                    value = json.loads(value_json)
                    if len(value) == 1:
                        value = value["value"]
                    status = value.get("error", None)
                    if not status:
                        status = value.get("status", ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR)
                        message = value.get("value") or value.get("message")
                        if not isinstance(message, str):
                            value = message
                            message = message.get("message")
                    else:
                        message = value.get("message", None)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
    
        exception_class: Type[WebDriverException]
        e = ErrorCode()
        error_codes = [item for item in dir(e) if not item.startswith("__")]
        for error_code in error_codes:
            error_info = getattr(ErrorCode, error_code)
            if isinstance(error_info, list) and status in error_info:
                exception_class = getattr(ExceptionMapping, error_code, WebDriverException)
                break
        else:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
    
        if not value:
            value = response["value"]
        if isinstance(value, str):
            raise exception_class(value)
        if message == "" and "message" in value:
            message = value["message"]
    
        screen = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
        if "screen" in value:
            screen = value["screen"]
    
        stacktrace = None
        st_value = value.get("stackTrace") or value.get("stacktrace")
        if st_value:
            if isinstance(st_value, str):
                stacktrace = st_value.split("\n")
            else:
                stacktrace = []
                try:
                    for frame in st_value:
                        line = frame.get("lineNumber", "")
                        file = frame.get("fileName", "<anonymous>")
                        if line:
                            file = f"{file}:{line}"
                        meth = frame.get("methodName", "<anonymous>")
                        if "className" in frame:
                            meth = f"{frame['className']}.{meth}"
                        msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                        msg = msg % (meth, file)
                        stacktrace.append(msg)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
        if exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            alert_text = None
            if "data" in value:
                alert_text = value["data"].get("text")
            elif "alert" in value:
                alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id=""]"}
E         (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.62); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
E       Stacktrace:
E       0   chromedriver                        0x0000000105732e68 chromedriver + 5090920
E       1   chromedriver                        0x0000000105729bd3 chromedriver + 5053395
E       2   chromedriver                        0x00000001052c5527 chromedriver + 447783
E       3   chromedriver                        0x0000000105314339 chromedriver + 770873
E       4   chromedriver                        0x00000001053144f1 chromedriver + 771313
E       5   chromedriver                        0x000000010535a304 chromedriver + 1057540
E       6   chromedriver                        0x000000010533b68d chromedriver + 931469
E       7   chromedriver                        0x00000001053576e1 chromedriver + 1046241
E       8   chromedriver                        0x000000010533b433 chromedriver + 930867
E       9   chromedriver                        0x0000000105306042 chromedriver + 712770
E       10  chromedriver                        0x000000010530726e chromedriver + 717422
E       11  chromedriver                        0x00000001056f43c9 chromedriver + 4834249
E       12  chromedriver                        0x00000001056f956d chromedriver + 4855149
E       13  chromedriver                        0x0000000105700502 chromedriver + 4883714
E       14  chromedriver                        0x00000001056fa29d chromedriver + 4858525
E       15  chromedriver                        0x00000001056cc0fc chromedriver + 4669692
E       16  chromedriver                        0x0000000105718c68 chromedriver + 4983912
E       17  chromedriver                        0x0000000105718e20 chromedriver + 4984352
E       18  chromedriver                        0x000000010572980e chromedriver + 5052430
E       19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80b01e4e1 _pthread_start + 125
E       20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80b019f6b thread_start + 15



I have tried this in simple code and its working and i have also changed the locator using ID,Xpath, CSS selector, name, class name etc. but still in above code its not taking that locator
```

Comment: The stacktrace contains: `{"method":"css selector","selector":"[id=""]"}`, which implies that it was not XPath but a css-selector, and where the id was empty